# ASP.NET4.0 URL rewriting-code for four parameters

Tags: asp.net, url-rewriting

I have a page go.aspx which accepts four parameters A,B,C,D like this go.aspx?A=a&B=b&C=c&D=d. The way url-rewrite will work is change it to go/a/b/c/d. But not all parameters are passed at a moment, all possible scenarios are:

1. go.aspx?A=a
2. go.aspx?A=a&B=b
3. go.aspx?A=a&B=b&C=c
4. go.aspx?B=b&C=c
5. go.aspx?C=c
6. go.aspx?C=c&D=d
7. go.aspx?B=b&C=c&D=d
8. go.aspx?B=b
9. go.aspx?B=b&D=d

Is writing route for each scenario the only option or can one route be modified to cover all the scenarios above?

Comment: Would there not be 16 possible scenarios?

Comment: Yeah there would be, but these are the one's which I would be handling any other cases would be ignored and the user redirected.